# How to display all tables in PostgreSql while having two schemes in db?

Tags: postgresql

There are 2 schemes in `my_db`. I need to display names of all tables in `scheme_one`. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL's [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html), like so:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'scheme_one';
```